# Handle/receive Async Post XML with C# asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, http, post

Working on in payment integration from the dev doc below.

https://dox.merchantwarrior.com/hosted-payments

I need to receive an "Asynchronous POST notifications" from my server side, the "notifyURL" of the documentation page above. The server is running a classic asp.net application.

How my "notifyURL.aspx" get the posted xml?
code in the "Page_Load" section? seems nothing in the "Request".

get the posted xml data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.